# How to properly update Anaconda?

Tags: updates, python, anaconda

I am trying to update my outdated Anaconda installation as Spyder reminded to do so. On the Spyder [help page](https://docs.spyder-ide.org/installation.html#updating-spyder) on how to update, it says to simply use `conda update anaconda` to update the whole distribution. However if I try to do so Anaconda tells me that it will actually be **downgraded** in the process:

```
The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:

  anaconda                                     5.3.1-py37_0 --> custom-py37_1
  mkl                                            2019.0-118 --> 2018.0.3-1
```

Is this behavior expected? If so what is the reason that an update leads to a downgrade at the end. This workflow seems kind of counter-intuitive.

Comment: hi, meet the same issue. Have you figured it out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's perfectly natural, the reason why the downgrade occurs is to put you back on the latest 'releases', which contains packages that are selected to work well together.

If you want the bleeding-edge version of each package run conda update --all

Hope this helps :)